# How can I align text inside a GnomeCanvas text item

Tags: gtk, canvas, gnome

I would like to have a GnomeCanvas text item and according to its content (and the content language) decide whether to align the text to the right or to the left.
I found one way to do it by changing the *anchor* property, but using this method would require me to manage the anchor position myself (change it to the right of the text bounding box when aligning to the right), and it seems there must be a simpler way.

EDIT: I see there is also the *justification* property, which allows me to align the text to the right. However, I still need to set the anchor point according to the language, instead of setting a bounding box that would apply to any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its about a month without another answer. I guess my first understanding was correct and there isn't another way with the canvas. My solution would then be to change the anchor to east and change the anchor point accordingly.